# How to Convert String to datetime which contains Time zone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

```py
string = 'Wed Apr 25 12:28:15 BST 2018'
string1 = 'Wed Mar 22 10:56:43 GMT 2017'
```

If we have string like above. How can we convert this to timestamp?
The expected format is ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')

I have tried:

```py
timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(string, '%a %b %d  %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'))
a=datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but here %Z flag only considering GMT time zone.
How to handle time zone like - 'CEST', 'BST'

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question. The problem is that `%Z` does not parse arbitrary time zone name abbreviations since those are ambiguous. You can find that in the [technical documentation, sect. 6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail).

Answer (score 0):

as commented, abbreviated tz names are ambiguous; just look for duplicates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) ...

So your best option is to *define* which abbreviation means which time zone. For your example, that could look like

```py
import dateutil

tzmap = {"GMT": dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/London"),
         "BST": dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/London")}

string = 'Wed Apr 25 12:28:15 BST 2018'
string1 = 'Wed Mar 22 10:56:43 GMT 2017'

for s in string, string1:
    print(dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos=tzmap))
# 2018-04-25 12:28:15+01:00
# 2017-03-22 10:56:43+00:00
```

Note: you don't *have* to use [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html); you would then have to extract the abbreviation before parsing, and handle it subsequently.